# How to read the headphone jack in android or iphone

Tags: android, iphone

I have two switches that I would like to connect to an android phone (and/or an iphone).  To be clear, I would like to connect a morse code key that has three connections: a ground, a dit and a dah.

Is there a way for me to sense that I have shorted between ground and either the left or right output of the headphone jack?

I see a lot of posts about reading the microphone but I'm interested in seeing both signals.

Comment: This question is too broad at the moment. It would be useful to have a make or model, as all android phones are different and have literally millions of hardware combinations...

Comment: I clicked to delete as it's off topic but I cannot do so.  I have flagged for moderator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phones don't have inputs on the earphone outputs, at least not so that you could use them.  Some can detect earphones or line-in, but it would be hard to do what you want through line-in - and most phones don't have line-in anyways.

Only the microphone can be used for button input.

[The Android documentation](https://source.android.com/accessories/headset/specification.html) tells you how to attach multiple buttons to the microphone input, and also tells you what events you will need to capture in your Android software.

Basically, you connect the microphone line to ground through a resistor with a specific value.  The causes a particular DC voltage on the microphone line, which Android evaluates and generates the events.

Comment: Thanks very much - I was trying to do this with no outboard hardware at all.  I see it's not possible, but a tiny little box with 2 resistors should be too hard at all.  Thanks again.